# Apache POI Java - Docx Charts and Graphs

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

Iv been working with XWPF documents for several weeks now and I have not been able to add charts. Pie charts, Bar charts. I plan to manually inject a chart with XML into the file but i think its excessive. I just want to add a chart to a Docx template. Aspose and javadocx are not options.

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/templates/standard.docx"));
//INSERT PIE CHART
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("output/output.docx");
document.write(out);
```

[UPDATE - The Easy Route]

Due to time it would take to successfully write an injection method, iv found a handy (Quick n dirty) way of adding charts. This is not the normal word charts but one generated from a library, stored as a picture and inserted.

First, i downloaded the library from http://knowm.org/open-source/xchart/xchart-example-code.

Second, one you have implemented your XWPFdocument, you create a chart and append it as an image.

```
private XWPFDocument add_chart(XWPFDocument document)
{
    // New Chart Element
    CategoryChart chart = new CategoryChartBuilder().width(500).height(400).theme(Styler.ChartTheme.GGPlot2).title(getClass().getSimpleName()).build();
    chart.setTitle("Issue Count");
    // Customize Chart
    Color[] sliceColors = new Color[]{new Color(27, 50, 119), new Color(58, 146, 56), new Color(0, 161, 222), new Color(154, 205, 102), new Color(246, 199, 182)};
    chart.getStyler().setSeriesColors(sliceColors);

    // Series
    chart.addSeries("Critical", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Count"})), new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Number[]{10})));
    chart.addSeries("High", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"High"})), new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Number[]{5})));
    chart.addSeries("Medium", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Medium"})), new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Number[]{2})));
    chart.addSeries("Low", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Low"})), new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Number[]{1})));

    // Create and store a jpg image of the chart, then append it to the document
    BitmapEncoder.saveBitmapWithDPI(chart, "tmp.jpg", BitmapFormat.JPG, 300);
    document.createParagraph().createRun().addPicture(new FileInputStream("tmp.jpg"), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "tmp.jpg", Units.toEMU(500), Units.toEMU(400));
    return document;
}
```

An example of one chart i made using the library:
[image: POI-chart-example]

Comment: Insert code here ^

Comment: Yea, you're pretty much going to have to write that yourself. Charts are only minimally supported in XSSF, and not at all supported in XWPF. You will have to use the CT classes to build it yourself. If you do work out a chart type or two, donation back to the community would likely be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below location's customise poi jar to read and modify chart of document file and then write into your actual document file.
using XWPFChart class you can use all method as we have available for POI EXCEL/PPT.

https://github.com/sandeeptiwari32/POI_ENHN/POI3.14.jar

below is simple example to read chart from MS-WORD File

```
public class PoiDocTest {
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("chart.docx"));
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        XWPFChart chart;
        for (POIXMLDocumentPart part : document.getRelations()) {
            if (part instanceof XWPFChart) {
                chart = (XWPFChart) part;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```